# Which transactions are restored with restoreCompletedTransactions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

What transactions are restored when I call restoreCompletedTransactions if the user has bought two or more non-renewing subscriptions one after another say one month apart. Do I get transactions for both of them with transactionState SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored or only for the one that is currently valid (meaning within current subscription period) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get all the transactions, that have been made. In the non-renewing case, this means a lot)

> When your application restores previous purchases, Store Kit deliveres EACH transaction to your application.

**EDIT**
Apple doesn't restore non-renewing at all, so you habe to create that mechanism yourself, otherwise, you'll be rejected—that really happened with my app.

Comment: While researching a bit more it seems that the non-renewing according to apple is not sent back as it is not supported by restore transactions. Do you know if this is true or not ?

Comment: Oh, man, i haven't read that part of your question, see my update